# Ubuntu 14.04 64bit iso file can't be written on DVD-R (from Windows)

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, iso, burning

I have downloaded the ISO file of Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. When I try and write the ISO with Windows to a DVD-R disk, it returns an error (Microsoft Error Code 0XC0AA0301):

[image]

I can write other kind of files to DVD, like images, videos, etc. This is happening with both Windows Disk Image Burner and Nero burning ROM.

Currently I'm using Windows 7, 64 bit. I don't want to install Ubuntu inside Virtual box. The DVD has enough space.

What can I do to burn the ISO to the DVD?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the error and link to it?

Comment: I have taken the screenshot. How can I send it ?? What's the link ??

Comment: Upload it to some image sharing site, get the link and edit into your question.

Comment: Can you ensure that the image was downloaded successfuly?

Comment: Upload the image to http://imgur.com and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/622783/edit) the question above and add the link to the image.

Comment: http://imgur.com/gallery/z4RkNJ8/new

Comment: @SubrahmanyaSriram link to the image itself, not the gallery.  Also, you say "DVD" and "CD".  The last statement is "CD".  Which are you actually using?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure that the image was successfully downloaded.

Comment: @ThomasW. DVD-R

Comment: http://imgur.com/z4RkNJ8

Comment: @SubrahmanyaSriram then let me edit your question accordingly.  DVD-R means "DVD Recordable", not DVD-ROM.

Comment: @SubrahmanyaSriram Next question: Is this a completely blank DVD?

Comment: @ThomasW. Okay, its DVD-ROM. And yeah, DVD is blank. I tried with 3 to 4 different new DVDs.

Comment: @SubrahmanyaSriram Are you ***absolutely certain*** the disk you are using is a DVD-ROM disk and not DVD-R or DVD+R?  And have you confirmed that you have a disk drive capable of writing to DVD-ROM?

Comment: This error message looks more like a problem with the disk than the file - it should just faithfully write a corrupted file to DVD & THEN fail to work,  but this is a write error.  Try rebooting Windows then yet another disk?

Comment: Okay, let me try all these things now. I'll get back. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

If you are having problem mounting files on dvd , you can use the live-usb to do that.
Just download win32 disk imager and install and then select the usb name(before that format the usb as fat32 or any other availible then ntfs) and burn the .iso or image file to the usb.
It is simple and effective.

Comment: I'm not sure this actually answers the OP's question...